# Working inside named range, referencing to row and column of named range

Tags: excel

So i have a question about named range and the way to reference and stay in them.

I am able to extract a specific row from the named range and then loop through all the column. but when i try to get the column number, i do not get it from within the named range but from the whole sheet.

```
    For Each rng1 In Tray_System.Rows
        If rng1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Truck Dumper" Then
            Debug.Print rng1.Address
            Set Tray_row = rng1
        End If
    Next

    For Each rng2 In tray_row.Columns
    If rng2.Value = "X" Then
        Debug.Print rng2.Column
    End If
    Next
```

I hope i'm being clear about my question, i want to make this short.

Basicaly, what i'm trying to do is:

- Look for which row in the named range starts with what i'm looking for (e.g. "Truck Dumper")
- From that row, look in each cell if the value is X
- For each cell with an X retrieve the name of the Column

The problem is the column number i get from rgn2.column isnt relative to the named range.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "i dont get it from within the named range but from the whole sheet." Does it mean your macro somehow checks cells outside of the range given? Or is it problem that you receive absolute column number?

Comment: Why don't you subtract rng2.column - tray_row.columns?

Comment: yes, the problem is that i get the absolute column number, so when i try to do something like Tray_system.cells(1, rng2.column) it goes out of my named range.

I think the substract idea will work, i try it now. will say if i succeed.

Comment: Yes it did, Thanks for the Answer ejlj. Thank you too Iowak for your time.

I am curious tho, Is substracting the range column number from the absolute column number the only way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not work with the cells directly, but with the data array. This is faster and you have only those data and not the whole sheet.

Example:

```
 aTray_System = Range("Tray_System").Value

 For lRow = LBound(aTray_System, 1) To UBound(aTray_System, 1)
  For lColumn = LBound(aTray_System, 2) To UBound(aTray_System, 2)
   'manipulate
   'aTray_System(lRow, lColumn) = aTray_System(lRow, lColumn) & "changed"
   'use
   Debug.Print aTray_System(lRow, lColumn)
  Next
 Next

 'write back, if changed
 Range("Tray_System").Value = aTray_System
```

Greetings

Axel